# DBeaver & MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, macos, dbeaver

I use `DBeaver` to watch an SQL database on `MySQL` **8+**.

and I have the following error message :

```
Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
```

And then, `DBeaver` won't let me connect to `MySQL`.

I've tried `useSSL=false` and `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` on the `Edit Driver Settings` but then it comes with this new error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

try upgrading your mysql connection driver mysql 8+ has taken a major upgrade it will not connect to the db less than version 8